# Char limit on custom blog-post form?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, widgets, forms, disqus

I want to setup a simple custom form for users to post, which will automatically:

- Subscribe user to updates (i.e. moderation approved, comment posted)
- Enable DISQUS xor IntenseDebate comments
- Publish to `/users-articles/`.

The form should look something like this:

> Title:
>
> Rich-text post (with char-limit):
>
> Tags:
>
> `Submit (goto login/register if unauthed)`

**Which plugin can I use to create this form?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with a plugin that is that specific but this answer should point you in the right direction if you're up to some dev work...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321914/wp-insert-post-with-a-form

Answer (score 0):

Formidable Pro (formidablepro.com) will allow you to have users create posts to either your wordpress blog or to a custom post types (I am assuming the mentioned users-articles is a custom post type). I think subscription to updates and the enabled comments would need to be done through other plugins though.

Comment: [You must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I emailed Formidable yesterday to see if they can provide the functionality I am looking for. Also, it seems that the [Quick Post Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/) might solve the issue.